# Count certain words in dataframe/matrix in R

Tags: r

I have this data , and what i want to do is to count the occurences(frequencies) of ONE, TWO, THREE in each columns

ex. 2 ONEs in the A column, 2 TWOs in the B column, 1 ONE in the C column etc

What function can i use to count certain words in R?

And how can i make a histogram out of this counts?

```
ABC <-read.csv("c:/Data/dataset.csv")

     A      B       C
1    TWO    ONE   THREE
2    ONE    ONE    TWO
3  THREE    TWO   THREE
4    ONE    TWO    ONE
5    TWO   THREE   TWO
```

Comment: The function to use is `table`.

Comment: `table(stack(ABC))` should do it, and please avoid moving the goal post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` to get the count of `unique` elements in the dataset by each column

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(ABC))
#      A B C
#ONE   2 2 1
#THREE 1 1 2
#TWO   2 2 2
```

---

Or we use `table`, after `unlist`ing the dataset and replicating the `names` of 'ABC'.  Note that here we are calling the `table` only once.

```
tbl <- table(unlist(ABC),names(ABC)[col(ABC)])
tbl
#        A B C
#  ONE   2 2 1
#  THREE 1 1 2
#  TWO   2 2 2
```

A slightly faster option would be to use `vapply` with `tabulate`

```
vapply(ABC, function(x) tabulate(factor(x)), numeric(3))
```

If we need a barplot

```
barplot(tbl, beside=TRUE, legend=TRUE)
```

Comment: what if i don't have qdapTools pacakage in my R? is there any other way  for me to count the words?

Comment: @Meredith YOu can use `table` (updated in my post)

Comment: @Meredith Do you need a `bar` plot or histogram?  You have only 3 columns

Comment: @ bar plot would be fine!

Comment: Thanks. just one more thing. - the order of bars are in a mess (it's in TWO-ONE-THREE order... is it possible for me to change the order?)

Comment: @Meredith Yes, We can convert to `factor` and specify the `levels` i.e. `barplot(table(factor(unlist(ABC), levels=c("ONE", "TWO", "THREE")),names(ABC)[col(ABC)]), beside=TRUE, legend=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(A=c('TWO','ONE','THREE','ONE','TWO'),B=c('ONE','ONE','TWO','TWO','THREE'),C=c('THREE','TWO','THREE','ONE','TWO'),stringsAsFactors=F);
sapply(df,table);
##       A B C
## ONE   2 2 1
## THREE 1 1 2
## TWO   2 2 2
```